# How to give access to a gke service for my gcloud vpn

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, gke-networking

I'm trying to  give access to the dev team to the database, but I don't want to expose the database pod(load balancer, etc ), and the pods ip changes from time to time. So i create a google cloud vpn, i can access the ip from my gke pod, but i cant access a service i created on gke, is it possible to access the gke service  from the vpn? thanks!

Comment: What is the error you are encountering when trying to access the service? You will need to identify first what is preventing you on that part. This [Solutions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setting-up-private-access-to-cloud-apis-through-vpn-tunnels) might also help and [this one](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps) as well.

Comment: thanks a lot im gonna look in to this. i created a service for my database pod, and when i try to access my database pod works fine , but if i try to access the service from this pod i get a timeout, im doing all this trough the gcloud vpn i created

Comment: Have you exposed the database with an internal network loadbalancer (TCP/UDP ILB)?